# Should I use DNS prefetch and preconnect when loading resources from CDN?

Tags: performance, cdn, resources, rel-dns-prefetch

In my web page I load around 12 resources from `jsdelivr` (CSS and JS).

Should I optimize it with one (or both) of following techniques? If yes, should I put the tags right before loading tags or at the beginning of the page?

- DNS prefetch
- DNS preconnect

Thanks.

Comment: How many unique domains your resources are from?

Comment: Just one: ```cdn.jsdelivr.net```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No doubt that resource hints like preconnect and prefetch improve performance. The only pitfall could be preconnecting too many domains. Based on an old StackOverflow thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445293/is-there-a-limit-to-how-many-domains-we-should-dns-prefetch-preconnect-with-ch) preconnecting more than 4-6 domains could consume resources on the client-side and generally not recommended (subject to testing in real-world scenario). But since you are speaking about a single domain, you should be able to preconnect without adverse effects.

A good practice is to issue a preconnect followed by a prefetch as fallback. The thread I had mentioned has the following example

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="http://example.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="http://example.com">
```

Regarding implementation, you should be fine by adding these within head tags.

For preconnect hint specifically, another implementation method (may be more effective) is via a http header. (In this case, I would recommend issuing preconnect via http header and prefetch from within the html document.) The below URL discusses both the implementation methods.

https://web.dev/preconnect-and-dns-prefetch/

Comment: Thanks. For ```CSS``` resources, I have tags to load them from CDN within ```<head>```  tag, but for ```JS``` resources they are at the end of the HTML file right before ```</body>``` tag. Now how to position ```preconnect``` and ```dns-prefetch``` tags to get the most out of them?

Comment: Since all the js and css files are from the same CDN domain, add the following within head tags <link rel="preconnect" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net" /> <link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net" rel="dns-prefetch">

Comment: `preconnect` also does a `dns-prefetch`. So `preconnect` should be sufficient.